# What will be the cost of trip for UK visa application calculated when there is a single booking for hotel and flight but cost is shared by the couple?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I’m applying for UK standard visa. I will be travelling with my husband and we are separately filling our applications. Since both of us are employed we will share the cost of the trip. Our hotel booking and flight itinerary is booked under both of our names. Do I need to include the full amount as the cost of trip and mention in the cover letter that my husband will share half of the expences? Or should I divide the total cost into 2 and mention only my expense in my form? Both of us are employed and are not dependent on each other and will submit proofs of the same.

Thanks

Comment: Don’t get bogged down in the weeds of minutiae. You’re applying separately so put down reasonable numbers that can be supported by your salary. Either way is fine, but the numbers must be reasonable.

Comment: @Preethi The application asks about travelling companions; link the applications up using the GWF numbers that get assigned as you complete them. Record the share of the planned cost in each application as ThE iLIEgAl aLiEn states

Comment: I always include the full amount as the costs of the trip. Next questions ask how much does the applicant pay and whether anybody else is paying for the trip and why. This is where the applicant can specify the details and explain them.

Comment: @user56513 want to write a full answer?

Answer (score 1):

Turning comments into an answer:

Include the full amount as the costs of the trip in each application. In the subsequent questions asking how much does the applicant pay and whether anybody else is paying for the trip and why, each applicant should specify the details and explain them.

The application also asks about travelling companions. To provide the ECO with the full picture, decide who is the *’primary’* applicant, complete their application first and make a note of the GWF reference number (assigned when an application is submitted). Then link the two applications by including the ‘primary applicant’s’ GWF number in the second application.

As [Augustine of Hippo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/56513/augustine-of-hippo) commmented, you could apply completely separately and just put down reasonable numbers that can be supported by your salary. However, IMHO being completely transparent about your travel plans is always a good idea and could even help avoid any possibility of a one application refused / one granted scenario.

As an aside, the UK does not require proof of travel/hotel reservations as part of submitting a visitor visa application (unless transiting). See [Documents you should not use as evidence](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk)